# replace ip address with domain name in redirect

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-7.5, ip-address, domain-name

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 virtual machine with IIS 7.5 hosting a ASP.NET MVC4 website. The WinServer has a public ip address. I also purchased a domain name. The domain name hosting company forwards requests to my server.
For example, when a customer types www.mycompany.com, the request is redirected to 217.151.XXX.XXX which is my server's public ip address.

When the customer is redirected to my server, everything is working. He sees a homepage in the web browser and with address www.mycompany.com in browser's address bar. However, when he browses through different pages in the websites and got redirected, the browser's address bar displays 217.151.xxx.xxx/order/detail instead of www.mycompany.com/order/detail.

I tired IIS url rewrite which rewrites 217.151.xxx.xxx/order/detail to www.mycompany.com/order/detail
But that results in the browser freezing, waiting for a response. My guess is that when IIS rewrites the url to www.mycompany.com/order/detail, it sends a request back to the domain name hosting company. The company interprets the request and redirects it back to 217.151.xxx.xxx which causes a infinite loop.

How can I have the domain name always displayed in the borwser's bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very general issue when we map domain with IP

Check this out.
http://help.lockergnome.com/windows2/Domain-static-IP-mapping--ftopict485575.html

Comment: This is helpful. Thanks. I found out the cause of the problem. I didn't configure the domain name server properly. After I bind the ip address to the domain name server in the right way, the ip address no longs shows in the browser address bar.

Comment: The included link redirects to the author's Patreon page.

Comment: This link is now dead.